# Summarize rows from a Pandas dataframe B that fall in certain time periods from another dataframe A

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking for an efficient way to summarize rows (in groupby-style) that fall in a certain time period, using Pandas in Python. Specifically:

The time period is given in dataframe A: there is a column for "start_timestamp" and a column for "end_timestamp", specifying the start and end time of the time period that is to be summarized. Hence, every row represents one time period that is meant to be summarized.

The rows to be summarized are given in dataframe B: there is a column for "timestamp" and a column "metric" with the values to be aggregated (with mean, max, min etc.). In reality, there might be more than just 1 "metric" column.

For every row's time period from dataframe A, I want to summarice the values of the "metric" column in dataframe B that fall in the given time period. Hence, the number of rows of the output dataframe will be exactly the same as the number of rows of dataframe A.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

**Additional Requirements**

- The number of rows in dataframe A and dataframe B may be large (several thousand rows).
- There may be many metrics to summarize in dataframe B (~100).
- I want to avoid solving this problem with a for loop (as in the reproducible example below).

**Reproducible Example**

*Input Dataframe A*

```
# Input dataframe A
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
    "start_timestamp": ["2022-08-09 00:30", "2022-08-09 01:00", "2022-08-09 01:15"],
    "end_timestamp": ["2022-08-09 03:30", "2022-08-09 04:00", "2022-08-09 08:15"]
})
df_a.loc[:, "start_timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_a["start_timestamp"])
df_a.loc[:, "end_timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_a["end_timestamp"])
print(df_a)
```

|  | start_timestamp | end_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-08-09 00:30:00 | 2022-08-09 03:30:00 |
| 1 | 2022-08-09 01:00:00 | 2022-08-09 04:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-08-09 01:15:00 | 2022-08-09 08:15:00 |

*Input Dataframe B*

```
# Input dataframe B
df_b = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp":[
        "2022-08-09 01:00", 
        "2022-08-09 02:00", 
        "2022-08-09 03:00", 
        "2022-08-09 04:00", 
        "2022-08-09 05:00", 
        "2022-08-09 06:00", 
        "2022-08-09 07:00", 
        "2022-08-09 08:00", 
    ],
    "metric": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
})
df_b.loc[:, "timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_b["timestamp"])
print(df_b)
```

|  | timestamp | metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-08-09 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-09 02:00:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-08-09 03:00:00 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-08-09 04:00:00 | 4 |
| 4 | 2022-08-09 05:00:00 | 5 |
| 5 | 2022-08-09 06:00:00 | 6 |
| 6 | 2022-08-09 07:00:00 | 7 |
| 7 | 2022-08-09 08:00:00 | 8 |

*Expected Output Dataframe*

```
# Expected output dataframe
df_target = df_a.copy()
for i, row in df_target.iterrows():

    condition = (df_b["timestamp"] >= row["start_timestamp"]) & (df_b["timestamp"] <= row["end_timestamp"])
    df_b_sub = df_b.loc[condition, :]
    
    df_target.loc[i, "metric_mean"] = df_b_sub["metric"].mean()
    df_target.loc[i, "metric_max"] = df_b_sub["metric"].max()
    df_target.loc[i, "metric_min"] = df_b_sub["metric"].min()
    
print(df_target)
```

|  | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | metric_mean | metric_max | metric_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-08-09 00:30:00 | 2022-08-09 03:30:00 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2022-08-09 01:00:00 | 2022-08-09 04:00:00 | 2.5 | 4.0 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2022-08-09 01:15:00 | 2022-08-09 08:15:00 | 5.0 | 8.0 | 2.0 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html#pandas.IntervalIndex) and [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.contains.html#pandas.IntervalIndex.contains) to create a dataframe with selected metric values and then compute the mean, max, min:

```
ai = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
    df_a["start_timestamp"], df_a["end_timestamp"], closed="both"
)
t = df_b.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series((ai.contains(x["timestamp"])) * x["metric"]), axis=1
)
df_a[["metric_mean", "metric_max", "metric_min"]] = t[t.ne(0)].agg(
    ["mean", "max", "min"]
).T.values
```

print(df_a):

```
      start_timestamp       end_timestamp  metric_mean  metric_max  metric_min
0 2022-08-09 00:30:00 2022-08-09 03:30:00          2.0         3.0         1.0
1 2022-08-09 01:00:00 2022-08-09 04:00:00          2.5         4.0         1.0
2 2022-08-09 01:15:00 2022-08-09 08:15:00          5.0         8.0         2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Code using **SQLITE3**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

df_a.to_sql('df_a',con=conn, index=False)
df_b.to_sql('df_b',con=conn, index=False)

pd.read_sql("""SELECT df_a.start_timestamp, df_a.end_timestamp 
            , AVG(df_b.metric) as metric_mean
            , MAX(df_b.metric) as metric_max
            , MIN(df_b.metric) as metric_min
              FROM 
              df_a INNER JOIN df_b 
              ON df_b.timestamp BETWEEN df_a.start_timestamp AND df_a.end_timestamp
              GROUP BY df_a.start_timestamp, df_a.end_timestamp""", con=conn)
```

Output:

[image]